# Is there any known limit for the size of an app uploaded and for the GBs assigned to a runtime?

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I was asked to deploy a Java EE application of 700MB (single EAR file) which requires 8 GB of RAM to execute.

I searched the docs but I didn't found any documented limit for those two parameters: size and RAM. Any URL or idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the application is limited to 1GB as mentioned [here](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/troubleshoot-app-health.html).

The Memory allocation is limited to 8GB per app, you can see this when you try to allocate more than 8GB in the Bluemix UI as it either resets to 8GB or if, using the toggle, doesn't allow you above 8GB.

If you app is pushing these limits then you might want to look at refactoring this app as per the [12factor](http://12factor.net/) app approach, so rather than one large monolithic app you have smaller more flexible apps.

As @ram-vennam said there is also the potential for staging timeouts when pushing a large app.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with uploading large applications is usually the network limitation - uploading and staging all the bits before the several timeouts. See [Deploying a Large Application](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/large-app-deploy.html) for more details.

If you have a fast network you could try:

```
cf push myappname -p largefile.ear -t 180 -m 8G -k 2G
```

If that fails during staging, set this env var, and push again

```
cf set-env myappname CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT 30
cf push myappname -p largefile.ear
```

Comment: "-t 10000" doesn't work. When using it I got: Server error, status code: 400, error code: 100001, message: The app is invalid: health_check_timeout Maximum exceeded: max 180s

Comment: -k 2G also fails with "Server error, status code: 400, error code: 100001, message: The app is invalid: disk_quota too much disk requested (must be less than 2048)" you should use -k 2000M for example.

Comment: You can change max timeout by setting BOSH deployment manifest property for `cloud_controller_ng`: `cc.maximum_health_check_timeout`. You can try to use `health-check-type: port` in app manifest.yml too.