# Issue uploading big apps

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I am uploading a big application (around 250Mb).
From home, it uploads in 1 hour more or less.

It worked sometimes, but most of the times I get this error (which in fact it doesn't seem to be a timeout):

> Uploading MyApp...
>
> Uploading app files from: D:\myapp
>
> Uploading 257.7M, 21 files
>
> Done uploading
>
> FAILED
>
> Error uploading application.
>
> Server error, status code: 500, error code: 0, message:

Any idea or suggestion?
Thanks!

More info added using CF_TRACE=true

> Uploading app files from: D:\myapp Uploading 257.7M, 21 files
>
> REQUEST: [2015-05-22T09:40:06+02:00] PUT
>   /v2/apps/43a2fdca-c836-XXXX-bf78-2b4be0d3c44e/bits?async=true HTTP/1.1
>   Host: api.eu-gb.bluemix.net Accept: application/json Authorization:
>   [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN] Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=e712ea65f4d42f7787e717f7b98532e222595d16d75370f17c3d4c618a74
>   User-Agent: go-cli 6.11.2-2a26d55 / windows
>
> [MULTIPART/FORM-DATA CONTENT HIDDEN] Done uploading
>
> RESPONSE: [2015-05-22T10:03:15+02:00] HTTP/1.1 500 Error Connection:
>   close Content-Length: -1 Content-Type: text/plain
>   X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL
>
> 500 Error: Connection error FAILED Error uploading application. Server
>   error, status code: 500, error code: 0, message: FAILED Error
>   uploading application. Server error, status code: 500, error code: 0,
>   message:

Comment: please post the output of "CF_TRACE=true cf push <app_name>". See also http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/troubleshoot-app-health.html

Comment: Added CF_TRACE=true info.

Comment: @Chemi You can upload up with a 1GB app, can you please turn on tracing and see what happens and try again?

Comment: @JeffSloyer I already turned on the tracing and posted the traces in the question. Do you mean I repeat the process now again? I should look for the app... not working on that nowadays.

Comment: If you are still interested for help on this app could you try it again and update your post?

Comment: I will, thanks. I will come back to you during this week. I need to recover the app and details.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading large applications can cause problems due to network restraints. Ram Vennam provides some more information in this Stack Overflow question that talks about deploying large applications:

- [Is there any known limit for the size of an app uploaded and for the GBs assigned to a runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340485/is-there-any-known-limit-for-the-size-of-an-app-uploaded-and-for-the-gbs-assigne/30355796#30355796)

I do not know anything about your application, but one suggestion could be to break up this up into a few smaller apps that all talk to each other (i.e. microservices). You can learn more about doing this on Bluemix here:

- [Online Store Application using Microservices and Bluemix](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/03/16/sample-application-using-microservices-bluemix/)

**Edit**: There is currently a known issue with staging sometimes returning a 500 error in the US-SOUTH region, also reported here:

- [Error deploying application from Eclipse to Bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373153/error-performing-while-deploying-application-from-eclipse-to-bluemix)

You can check status here:

- [Bluemix System Status](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that post. But I opened a new question as I am not getting any kind of timeout. Or the error doesn't say that but perhaps under the covers it is a timeout. That's the question. Note: I am aware of US issue, but I am using UK.