# Error deploying application from Eclipse to Bluemix

Tags: eclipse, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

While pushing an application from Eclipse to Bluemix, I received this error:

```
Error: Client error - Error performing operation: 500 Error
```

I tried multiple times but received the same error whenever pushing the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently experiencing some issues in our South region. We expect these issues to be resolved shortly.  For updates on the status of our runtimes, please see the following:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status